# xamarin is not showing in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, xamarin

I installed Xamarin first and then installed Visual Studio 2013. But when I open Visual Studio it doesn't show the Xamarin components when I try to create a new project for Xamarin.

What I should do so that I can work on Xamarin with the help of Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: You should install Xamarin after installing Visual Studio

Comment: But I have alreday installed all components of xamarin then installed the visual studio. Now I have uninstall all the things first. Is there no other solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

For this you must install "Extensions for Visual Studio" plug in, which is delivered with Xamarin. So you must run XamarinInstaller again - but you don't have to uninstall anything, just run it again.

Update: As I see, they offer on their website "Visual Studio tool for Xamarin". So try this one.